# JavaScript: how to check if elements in array are the correct length

Tags: javascript, arrays, validation

I have an array named "Items", with the contents of:

```
0: {ID: "50425", Item: "1", Agenda: "61163", Title: "Comment"}
1: {ID: "50425", Item: "2", Agenda: "62394", Title: "Program"}
2: {ID: "50425", Item: "3", Agenda: "57122", Title: "Action"}
3: {ID: "50425", Item: "4", Agenda: "56234", Title: "Future"}
4: {ID: "50425", Item: "5", Agenda: "33325", Title: "Report"}
5: {ID: "50425", Item: "6", Agenda: "33326", Title: "Rights"}
6: {ID: "50425", Item: "7", Agenda: "33327", Title: "Division"}
7: {ID: "50425", Item: "8", Agenda: "41726", Title: "Award"}
```

I need to learn how to check if Item and Agenda have valid values.

Item should be of length of at least 1, no greater than 3, and a positive numeric value
Agenda should be the same, but no greater than 5 digits long.

I have looked up information on how to check if an array has data in it, but I have not learned how to check is the values in the array are valid.

Is there any examples someone can point me to, or willing to share how to achieve this that would be great.

I do not have much code done yet, only the part that I read the data from the excel file, and then assign it to a scope variable.

```
$scope.ProcessExcel = function (data) {
     //Read the Excel File data.
     var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
         type: 'binary'
     });
     //Fetch the name of First Sheet.
     var firstSheet = workbook.SheetNames[0];
     //Read all rows from First Sheet into an JSON array.
     excelRows = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[firstSheet]);
     excelRows.forEach(function (element) {
         element.MeetingID = $scope.meetingId;
     });
     //Display the data from Excel file in Table.
     $scope.$apply(function () {
         
         $scope.Items = excelRows;
         $scope.IsVisible = true;
         $scope.disableSubmit = false;            
     });
     console.log(excelRows);
 };
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Erasmo

**EDIT**

Kamen I like your solution and I want to make it work especially now that you showed me how to get all the values from the valid and invalid rows.

One thing I wonder if you have a suggestion:

My array:

```
let excelRows2 = [
    { ID: "50425", Item: "4441", Agenda: "6", Title: "Comment" },
    { ID: "50425", Item: "-2", Agenda: "694", Title: "Program" },
    { ID: "50425", Item: "344", Agenda: "522", Title: "Action" },
    { ID: "50425", Item: "444", Agenda: "-1", Title: "Future" },
    { ID: "50425", Item: "544", Agenda: "adfas", Title: "Report" },
    { ID: "50425", Item: "6778", Agenda: "36", Title: "Rights" },
    { ID: "50425", Item: "7bbbbb", Agenda: "327", Title: "Division" },
    { ID: "50425", Item: "-1", Agenda: "4726", Title: "Award" }
];
```

In this array, only the 3rd row is a valid row.

When I print the values in the manner you showed me:

```
let validRows = excelRows2.filter((row) => rowIsValid(row));
let invalidRows = excelRows2.filter((row) => !rowIsValid(row));

console.log(validRows);
console.log(invalidRows);
```

Then I have 2 arrays.

How can I print the invalid and invalid values on the page and keeping the original order?

Thank you kindly.

**EDIT #2**

I think I came up with a solution:

```
let excelRows2 = [
    { ID: "50425", AgendaItem: "4441", LegistarID: "6", Title: "Comment" },
    { ID: "50425", AgendaItem: "-2", LegistarID: "694", Title: "Program" },
    { ID: "50425", AgendaItem: "344", LegistarID: "522", Title: "Action" },
    { ID: "50425", AgendaItem: "444", LegistarID: "-1", Title: "Future" },
    { ID: "50425", AgendaItem: "544", LegistarID: "adfas", Title: "Report" },
    { ID: "50425", AgendaItem: "6778", LegistarID: "36", Title: "Rights" },
    { ID: "50425", AgendaItem: "7bbbbb", LegistarID: "327", Title: "Division" },
    { ID: "50425", AgendaItem: "-1", LegistarID: "4726", Title: "Award" }
];

excelRows2.forEach(function (row) {
    var response = rowIsValid(row);
    if (!response) {
        row.IsValid = false;
    }
    else {
        row.IsValid = true;
    }
});

function rowIsValid(row) {
    return (
        (fitsLength(row.AgendaItem, 1, 3) && isPositive(row.AgendaItem)) &&
        (fitsLength(row.LegistarID, 1, 5) && isPositive(row.LegistarID))
    );
}

function fitsLength(str, min, max) {
    return str.length >= min && str.length <= max;
}

function isPositive(strNum) {
    return parseInt(strNum, 10) > 0
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's as simple as all your conditions matching for a given row, and you can break the individual checks into separate functions for clarity. The strings you check simply by length and the numbers you parse from the strings and then do a comparison:

```js
let excelRows = [
    { ID: "50425", Item: "1", Agenda: "61163", Title: "Comment" },
    { ID: "50425", Item: "2", Agenda: "62394", Title: "Program" },
    { ID: "50425", Item: "3", Agenda: "57122", Title: "Action" },
    { ID: "50425", Item: "4", Agenda: "56234", Title: "Future" },
    { ID: "50425", Item: "5", Agenda: "33325", Title: "Report" },
    { ID: "50425", Item: "6", Agenda: "33326", Title: "Rights" },
    { ID: "50425", Item: "7", Agenda: "33327", Title: "Division" },
    { ID: "50425", Item: "8", Agenda: "41726", Title: "Award" }
]; // dummy assignment, in the original example that would be the result of XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(...)

function rowIsValid(row) {
    return (
        (fitsLength(row.Item, 1, 3) && isPositive(row.Item)) &&
        (fitsLength(row.Agenda, 1, 5) && isPositive(row.Agenda))
    );
}

function fitsLength(str, min, max) {
    return str.length >= min && str.length <= max;
}

function isPositive(strNum) {
    return parseInt(strNum, 10) > 0
}

excelRows.map((row) => console.log(rowIsValid(row)));
```

Edit: to filter the valid and invalid rows, you can simply do the following:

```js
let validRows = excelRows.filter((row) => rowIsValid(row));
let invalidRows = excelRows.filter((row) => !rowIsValid(row));
```

Comment: Thank you Kamen, I will try your example. I thought I needed to use a loop in order to accomplish the task; what is the purpose of .map function? I will try to fit your example with my task at hand. Once again, thank you.

Comment: I think I can make your code example work. I just need to get comfortable adapting it to my needs. Just one question I hope you don't mind, would it be easy to show, how to return a message that tells the user about the items that returned false? Thank you very much,

Comment: Array.map() can serve like a for loop, but with a simpler syntax - it takes all the entries in the array and passes each of them as the first argument of the function inside - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map - so `(row) => console.log(rowIsValid(row))` will be called once for each entry in the array. You can use that or Array.filter() to filter valid and invalid entries, see my edited original answer.

Comment: I can see the invalid and valid values. I updated my question. I wonder if it is possible to keep the original order of the array to then show it on a page? Otherwise what I think I can do is to have to tables, one that will only show if there are invalid values. Perhaps you see a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: Kamen, I think I came up with a simple solution. I am not sure if best practice, but I edited my question, and the potential solution I came up with is under EDIT #2. If you have a more elegant method to achieve this task, please let me know. Thank you very much.

Comment: At first glance you can simplify what's in the for loop to just `row.isValid = rowIsValid(row)`, i.e. dropping the if-else and the extra variable. It will be a bit more readable that way in my opinion. Sometimes it might not be a good idea to write directly into the input data, but you'll decide that for yourself.